# Essential singularity of $f(z)= e^{1/(z-1)}/(e^z - 1)$

Tags: complex-analysis

Let $f(z)= e^{1/(z-1)}/(e^z - 1)$. I know that $z = 2kπi$ are simple poles, but how do I show rigorously that $z=1$ is an essential singularity? Do I have to compute the Laurent series around $1$, because I do not see how to handle the $e^z - 1$ in the denominator.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Laurent series of $e^{1/(z-1)}=1+1/(z-1)+1/2!(z-1)^2+. .....$

at $z=1.$ but remaining part of your function is analytic at $z=1$. Therefore the principal part has infinitely many nonzero terms and hence $z=1$ is an essential singularity of $f(z)$.

Comment: Can you explain " The principal part has infinitely many nonzero terms"? That is, since we are dividing the Laurent series you wrote with another infinite polynomial, how does this affect its terms?

Comment: $z=a$ is an essential singularity of $f$ if the Laurent series of $f$ has infinitely many terms containing negative powers of $z-1.$ The part of the series containing all such negative powers is called principal part of the series. In the above expression you can see that. The term $1/(e^z-1)$ is analytic at $z=1$ and it has a power series expansion at $z=1.$